# Retracting only a Rule and not Facts of the same predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a set of Rules and a set of Facts with the same predicate

```
p(1).
p(2).
g(1,1).
h(3,2).
p(X):- g(X,Y).
p(X):- h(X,Y).
```

I would like to do a retractall-like predicate and remove only the rules and not the facts. So something like:

```
retractRules(p(X)).
```

How would one do this in Prolog?

Comment: You're going to get a "discontiguous predicate" warning with this code since definitions of clauses for `p/1` are separated by definitions of a different predicate. That stands the risk of `p(X)` clauses not being recognized at all.

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my prior answer due to a flaw in my logic which only relied on `retract/1`.

Building on Paulo Moura's idea of using `clause/3`, here's a solution using the ISO predicate `clause/2`, making it a little more portable:

```
retractRules(R) :-
    clause(R, B),
    B \== true,
    retract(:-(R, B)),
    fail.
retractRules(_).
```

The assumption here is that your rule was dynamically created in the first place, and declared to be a dynamic predicate using the appropriate directive (`:- dynamic`). For example, somewhere before, you would have had something like:

```
assertz(:-(p(X), g(X,Y))).
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the standard `retract/1` predicate to retract only facts. A call such as `retract((p(_) :- Body))` retracts facts and instantiates `Body` to `true`.

Given that you're using SWI-Prolog, a **non-portable** solution is to use `clause/3` to get the references to rules and then delete the clauses with those references using `erase/1`. Assuming `p/1` is a dynamic predicate:

```
?- forall((clause(p(_), Body, Ref), Body \== true), erase(Ref)).
```

You could of course retract **all** clauses and then assert back only the facts but that sounds overkill:

```
?- forall((retract(p(X) :- Body), Body == true), assertz(p(X)).
```

Comment: A solution that works in GNU Prolog and SWI Prolog is using `clause/2`:  `retractRules(R) :- clause(R, B), B \== true, retract(:-(R, B)), fail.`